# Lifting Support Under Panel BMW

Tags: troubleshooting, bmw

My mom just drove above something and this piece fell of of the car (BMW series 3 touring). Can we drive without it for a moment? Or is this a really important piece?

[image: Car Piece Image]

[image: Car Piece Image]

This is the info on the piece:

51717123311 - 09

118844    10      1

GERMANY

IN > TE.S < VAR.B

OUT > PP-GF30 <

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thats just a piece of plastic, needed to avoid scratching the body-frame when lifting the car.

Assuming no further damage (please check, as it is likely that something else is bent or destroyed) it shouldn't be a big deal. Those pieces cost ~10$, I think one can just slide them in without brute force.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not an important piece. TBH, I don't know *exactly* what it is for, however, I can tell you it is not something which is going to affect how the vehicle operates or the safety of the vehicle in any way. I believe it is one of those pieces which can be abused to protect other parts of the underside of the vehicle. Not anything which is an emergency, but should be replaced so as it can continue to provide that protection.

Put it this way, if it is there to provide the protection and has been beaten up, it's done its job. However, if it's been beaten up, it stands to reason what ever it is protecting might get beaten up as well with it not being there to do its job.